# Leave z in one side of the equation...

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How would  leave z in one side of the equation?And prove that I can do this for points that lie near $(1, 0, 1) $ ?

$ xy + z + 3xz^2 = 4 $

This would imply that

$ z (1 + 3xz) = 4 - xy $

And than I have no idea of what i should do...

Comment: It's a quadratic in $z$.

Comment: you mean I should use the quadratic formula and that's it?

Comment: and then calculate the limit in (1,0,1) maybe?

Comment: Yup, that's it! I'm not sure what you mean by finding the limit at $(1,0,1)$, since $z$ will be a function of $x$ and $y$. Since it's quadratic, there will be two answers when $x=1,$ and $y=1$.

Comment: I see that i can not take the limit a $(1, 0, 1)$... But i dont understand why there will be two answers, when $x=1$ and $y=1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$xy + z + 3xz^2 = 4$$
by rewriting
$$ 3xz^2+ z+(xy -4)=0$$
Notice that above equation is quadratic in $z$
So, by Using quadratic formula we get

$$z=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1-4(xy-4)(3x)}}{6x}$$

Comment: From this I would think that $4(xy-4)(3x) = 12x^2y-48$ is minor or equal than 1, so that the sqare root makes sense. This implies that $y = 49/12x^2$ and $x = sqrt(49/12y)$...